# Grafana Regex fiter by name

Tags: grafana, influxdb

These are iPads and phones with their battery levels monitored in Grafana.
How can I filter it, so it will show me the iPads only (starting with device name "H.*")
When I try regex like "/^H.*$/" it doesn't work.

Thanks

[image: grafana]

[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

Not a regex expert, but `^H.$` will only match `H.` literally.

You need to match any amount and type of possible following characters as well; you can do that for numbers, lowercase, and uppercase characters with `\w*`.

So in your case, `^H.\w*$` should work.

**EDIT**

After having a closer look at your pictures, I realize that the names you want to filter for are rows of the column `device_name`, not the column names themselves. However, the used `Filter by name` filters the column names, in your case `device_name` and `battery_level`. Since neither fit the regex, 'No data' is returned.

To filter the results of a column you have to use `Filter data by values`. You have to specify the field, i.e. the column `device_name`, use `Regex` as type for `Match` and then enter the regex in the `Value` field.

Use the regex as explained above.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, but unfortunately, that didn't work

Comment: What is it showing when you try it? 'No data' again or an error?

Comment: it's showing "No data" again